# I need help translating military terms from a foreign language

Tags: translation, english

I am translating a World War II memoir from Hungarian to English. I keep running into certain words which I understand perfectly, but have a hard time finding a proper translation. Can you guys help me out? Not with the translation itself, but to find a good English equivalent.

The original word is "karpaszományos". The word itself literally translates as "person with a ribbon on his arm". It means a soldier, either conscripted or volunteer, who completed high school. That was a fairly high academic achievement in the 1930's, so these guys received special privileges in the army, and were often sent to NCO training or officer school. Even if they didn't want to, they were usually promoted to sergeants.

So, they're NOT cadets, NOT officer candidates, NOT simply conscripts and it's NOT a rank but a privilege class. For that matter no English speaking army ever had privilege classes.

A "karpaszományos" wore a thin band around the arms of his jacket, indicating his status. It was not rank insignia. Here is a picture of a "karpaszományos" jacket.

[image: "Karpaszományos" jacket, see the wrists]

I am looking for a single, descriptive English word to denote these soldiers, which can be used when addressing them (similarly to calling someone by his rank), or can be a title before their actual rank ("karpaszományos zászlós" = ensign with armband).

I don't think "armband" can be used here in any form because armbands are generally used to indicate a person on special duty (MPs, traffic controllers, officers on duty). The word "paszomány" means something like lacing, braiding, knotted decoration.

Comment: Have you tried using a thesaurus?

Comment: There's no thesaurus for this. This is a very old official term which only existed in Hungary and isn't in use since 1945.

Comment: Googling the word you are interested in and using google translate yields many descriptions.  It sounds like cadet would be a reasonable term until they received their commission as a reserve officer

Comment: Do you know if the rank still exists today?

Comment: draftee, maybe?

Comment: It's not a cadet. It's merely a soldier with a high school diploma. He may or may not become a cadet later, but most of them didn't. Draftee means any conscripted soldier. Like I said, it's not a rank, and it doesn't exist since 1945.

Comment: Considering this is a question about translating a specific term into English, it may be better suited to [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/), though I'm unsure whether they accept questions of this type.

Comment: The descriptions, from Hungarian museums, indicate that these men because of their education were receiving additional training and commissioned in the reserve officer corp.  The closest equivalent is cadet since its not a rank but an indicator.  Cadets have rank amended on to the title cadet private cadet sergeant etc.

Comment: No. Cadets were specifically officer candidates, and they were actually called cadets. These guys didn't always become officers, even reserve officers, or aspired to become one. My grandfather was also a "karpaszományos" ensign, but he never even thought of pursuing a professional military career.

Comment: @TamásPolgár: There really isn't an English equivalent. I myself joined the United States Air Force in 1987. Because I had two years of courses at a univertsity (incomplete Bachelor's degree,) I got a boost in rank after I completed basic training in the Air Force. There was no special name for it. I went from rank "Airman Basic" to "Airman First Class" without the otherwise required time in the rank of "Airman." Just use the original Hungarian word and explain it in a footnote or in the text. The cultural background of the term is more interesting than a simple translation.

Answer (score 3):

### The word you're looking for may not exist

The word you describe is a cultural term, denoting status that is specific to the culture that created it.  If English speaking cultures don't have an equivalent social status, then English won't have an equivalent word.

If this is the case, then the best thing to do is to simply use the original term, with a footnote (or similar) explaining what the word means.

Comment: I thought of that, but that's a quite lame solution. Maybe as a last resort, if really nothing comes up.

Comment: @TamásPolgár it's not lame.  Some words have no good translation, and it's better to fully explain what the original meant than it is to pick a superficially similar word that strips the text of its connotations. It's like translating the word "bitch" to "female dog".  It's technically accurate word for word, but it doesn't accurately translate what the writer meant.

Comment: I still think it's lame, but there doesn't seem to be a better option...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting a Hungarian-English dictionary if you don't already have one. I sometimes find myself bringing my Swedish-English one out when free online resources fail me.

However, I'm not sure your military-grade exists as you describe it in many armies.

How about using "[private first class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_first_class)" or "[lance corporal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lance_corporal)" (sometimes also known as "vice corporal" but that may be only in Sweden)?

If you compare duties and authority between your rank and those maybe you'll find a fit, or be able to go with the next best fit.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something like an "honors graduate" of military training or the more generic "decorated soldier."